# How come the first round of my animation doesn't work properly?

Tags: css, animation, css-animations, css-transitions, transition

I am making a website with an animation, which contains 5 different pictures that transition into the other continuesly.

Here's my code:

```
<div class="carousel">
</div>


.carousel {
  margin-top: 40px;
  background-image: url(/images/jekyllrb.png);
  background-size: cover;
  display: flex;
  justify-self: center;
  width: 880px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 40px 345px 0px 345px;
  animation-name: turning;
  animation-duration: 20s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  transition: all 2s;
}

@keyframes turning {
  2% {background-image: url(/images/bootstrap.png)}
  20% {background-image: url(/images/bootstrap.png)}
  22% {background-image: url(/images/corefx.png)}
  40% {background-image: url(/images/corefx.png)}
  42% {background-image: url(/images/facebookdesign.png)}
  60% {background-image: url(/images/facebookdesign.png)}
  62% {background-image: url(/images/yeoman.png)}
  80% {background-image: url(/images/yeoman.png)}
  82% {background-image: url(/images/jekyllrb.png)}
  100% {background-image: url(/images/jekyllrb.png)}
}
```

The thing is: when I reload my page, there is no smooth transition from one picture to the other, only after the whole animation has looped through once, it starts doing the animation the way it should. Why is this happening and how can i solve it?

Comment: Are you certain that everything has loaded before the animations start? It would be useful to see your HTML.

Comment: I use an empty div. How can I check if everything has loaded?

Comment: Do you have something like window.onload= some initialising function or does your site just start running assuming that everything is loaded OK?

Comment: No nothing like that. Do I need to add a function so the animation gets loaded fully?

Comment: https://blissful-mayer-b290d6.netlify.app/ this is what's happening

Comment: the way to do this is to set every image in the background and background-position to show only one, then via animation reset background-position for each  to swap them ...

Comment: Please could you show us your code (HTML and Javascript if  any).

Comment: @G-Cyrillus could you show an example of the code that I could use? I tried what you suggested but it didn't work, so I don't know if I did the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

to respond to your comment, here is an example with background-position:

```css
.carousel {
  margin: 40px auto;
  width: 800px;
  height:450px;
  box-shadow:0 0 5px;
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1002/800/450), url(https://picsum.photos/id/1003/800/450), url(https://picsum.photos/id/1004/800/450), url(https://picsum.photos/id/1005/800/450), url(https://picsum.photos/id/1006/800/450);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 0, 800px 0, 800px 0, 800px 0, 800px 0;
  animation-name: turning;
  animation-duration: 20s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}


@keyframes turning {
  0% {
    background-position: 0 0, 800px 0, 800px 0, 800px 0, 800px 0;
  }
  20% {
    background-position: -800px 0, 0 0, 800px 0, 800px 0, 800px 0;
  }
  40% {
    background-position: 800px 800000px, -800px 0, 0 0, 800px 0, 800px 0;
  }
  60% {
    background-position: 800px 800000px, 800px 800000px, -800px 0, 0 0, 800px 0;
  }
  80% {
    background-position: 800px 0, 800px 800000px, 800px 800000px, -800px 0, 0 0;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0 0, 800px 0, 800px 0, 800px 80000px, -800px 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel"></div>
```

---

to **fade them** *(carousel gets things running around to my understanding)* , you need opacity and different containers. body + 2 pseudos can easily set a fade effect through 3 images. if you use multipkle background and position, you can increase the number of image to fade in-out through.

basic example inspired from : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/vsrqi

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/id/1008/800/400");
  background-size: cover;
  animation: changeBackground 10s infinite;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0; 
  margin:0;
}

body , #page{
  display: flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  position: static;
}

body:before,
body:after {
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  background-size: cover;
  animation: bgfade 10s infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  opacity: 1;
}

#page {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2000;
  width: 70%; 
  max-width: 1020px;
  min-height: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
  padding: 1em;
  border-radius: 1em;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px white;
  color: white;
  font-size:calc(10px + 3vw);
}

body:before {
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/id/1011/800/400");
  animation-direction: alternate-reverse;
}

body:after {
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/id/1006/800/400");
}

@keyframes bgfade {
  0%,
  66% {
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 100;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 0;
  }
}

a {
  color: gold;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
  run it full page mode too
</div>
```

Comment: Hmmm I think you misunderstood what I am looking for. I want the pics to fade-out and fade-in after eachother. I'm recreating the Github Pages website: https://pages.github.com/, so I want the animation to be the same. The animation is as I want it to be, but only after the first cycle. The first cycle is flickery, not as smooth as the second cycle, as you can see in the link that I posted of the website.

Comment: @MFA86 for a fading in out, you need to use a pseudo and opacity, body,body:before,  body:after will do for 3 images, for more you will need again background-position and swap image while they are hidden . here is an old example you can inspire yourself from : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/rmOVJM or with 3 img https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/vsrqi (updated with new image, old ones where off-line).